# Blank Application does not recognize new Layout template page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I honestly cannot explain this. It's a completely brand new, empty Asp.Net Core MVC Application. Just duplicated the existing layout and tried to use it on the privacy action.

ASP.Net Core MVC (Core version 8.0.1)

Comment: Typo?  The file name has an underscore, but the code is looking for a file without an underscore.  Which of course it can't find.

Comment: Agghh..you are correct. Note to self. Stop coding after 10 hours. Good catch David.